# C - How to parse file (or string) with certain format

Tags: c, parsing

I have a file in the form:

```
PROPERTY1=VALUEX
PROPERTY2=VALUEY
...
```

And I want to write a function like this:

```
int find_property(char* file_contents, char* property_name, char* value)
```

That will take the file's contents as a char*, and then find the property and assign it's value to char* value. Obviously returning 0 if it found the property and 1 if it did not.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
char file_contents[500];
char* property = "PROPERTY1";
char value[500];

load_file_contents("file.txt", file_contents);
if(find_property(file_contents, property, value) == 1){
    // Do something with 'value'
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you need help with something specific that you have tried?

Comment: @melpomene sorry I was writing that on the fly. Thanks for the helpful comment...

Answer (score 0):

I terminated the file with a '$' character and this works:

```
    char c = file_contents[0];
    char property_name[100] = {};
    char value[100] = {};
    int in_property = 1;
    int in_value = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int t = 0;
    while(c != '$'){
        if(c == '='){
           in_property = 0;
           in_value = 1;
           property_name[i] = '\0';
           i = 0;
           // continue; 
        } else if(c == '\n'){
           in_property = 1;
           in_value = 0;
           value[i] = '\0';
           if(strcmp(property_name, property) == 0){
              sprintf(result, value);
              return;
           }
           i = 0;
        } else if(in_property == 1){
            property_name[i] = c;
            i++;
        } else if(in_value == 1){
            value[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
        t++;
        c = file_contents[t];
    }
```